How to prove that Trace-class operators are Hilbert-Schmidt operators

Prove that if $T$ is a Trace-class operator on the Hilbert space $H$, then $T$ is also a Hilbert-Schmidt operator.

The definitions of Trace-class operators and Hilbert-Schmidt operators are as in this question: Hilbert-Schmidt operators and Trace-class operators.
$T$ is a Trace-class operator $\Rightarrow$ $\sum_\alpha\langle|T|e_\alpha,e_\alpha\rangle<+\infty. $
$\sum_\alpha\|Te_\alpha\|^2=\sum_\alpha\langle |T|^2e_\alpha,e_\alpha\rangle$. But how to prove that $\sum_\alpha\langle|T|^2e_\alpha,e_\alpha\rangle $ is controlled by $\sum_\alpha\langle|T|e_\alpha,e_\alpha\rangle$? (We may assume $\alpha \in \mathbb N$)
I think that the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality can't work.
Many thanks in advance!

Let $T$ be a trace-class operator. Then $|T|$ is a positive, compact operator, so by spectral theorem, it admits an orthonormal eigenbasis $\{e_\alpha\}$. Let the eigenvalue of $|T|$ associated to the eigenvector $e_\alpha$ be $\lambda_\alpha$, which is non-negative. Then,
$$\sum_\alpha \lambda_\alpha = \sum_\alpha \langle |T|e_\alpha, e_\alpha \rangle < \infty$$
But now,
$$\sum_\alpha \langle |T|^2 e_\alpha, e_\alpha \rangle = \sum_\alpha \lambda_\alpha^2 \leq (\sum_\alpha \lambda_\alpha)^2 < \infty$$

Oh yes I have to use the spectral decomposition. I forgot that, being very stupid. Thanks a lot!
